# How to work with a datetime.datetime object returned from an Oracle query in Python

Tags: python, oracle, datetime

I have a query against an Oracle database using cx_Oracle.  The results from the query come as
`(datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47),)`

I get this by using the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import obi
from datetime import datetime

conn = obi.connect_obi()
query = obi.run_query(conn, "SELECT column FROM table_name")

for i in query:
    print i
```

What I want to do is extract the time, date, etc. from the results.

I've tried using various datetime methods, but I can't figure how to access the individual elements from the returned list.  I get various errors about it being a tuple, a list ,etc depending on what attempts I make.  I've looked at examples on Google and I can get those to work fine - what do I need to do differently to successfully access the time/date in this datetype?

Thanks!
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = (datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47),)
```

is a tuple.

```
dt = x[0]
```

is the first element, which is your datetime.

```
dt.year
```

is the year of the datetime.
etc.

Comment: Happy to help.  Click the checkbox outline next to this answer to "accept" it and close the question.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

The returned value, `(datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47),)` is really a tuple. Note that it is enclosed in parenthesis and (most importantly) it has a comma just after the date. Just like a comma between two expressions turn them in a pair tuple (such as `1, 2`) a comma after some expression turns the value in a tuple with just one element. More about it in the [this section of the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (more specifically [here](http://awurl.com/SWl1IR3iB)).

An example:

```
>>> (datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47),)
(datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47),)
>>> t = (datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47),)
```

To get the date, just get the first element of the tuple

```
>>> date = t[0]
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 25, 14, 30, 47)
>>> date.year
2010
>>> date.month
11
```